# Electron app | Custom installer with electron-builder

Tags: node.js, electron, nsis, electron-builder

I want to create a custom installer for my electron app.
During the installation, i want a form who ask information like ip server for example and i want to use this information in my main.js

Actually, i use a config.js file for my config variable but i want set this variable during the installation ? I search on a lot of topic but i can't find something ..

For create my exe file i use electron-builder with this script

`"build": "electron-builder build --win --publish never"`

My config.js file actually :

```
const config = {};

config.database = {}
config.database.host = "server"
config.database.port = 123456
config.database.user = "user"
config.database.password = "password"
config.database.database = "database"

config.agentId = 3

module.exports = config
```

Someone have a solution or can help me please ??

Thank you.
Marvin.

Comment: I think you would want a [custom NSIS script](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#custom-nsis-script) if you're only targeting Windows with NSIS. Since this is Electron, though, it would probably be much easier to work within the browser tech. You could make the install-time config screen a page of your web app that your `main.js` opens in a separate window on first run, before it needs to have that config in place. From the user's perspective, this would seem to be another step in the install process. There are big Electron apps that handle it that way.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to create custom installer page where the specific information is entered.

You can build it within NSIS using nsDialogs - you need to write the script for that page that process the variables and so on, see the Examples folder for quick start.

If you have no experience I can recommend you **Install Designer** (http://install-designer.com/) which is a GUI tool for designing custom NSIS pages without any scripting (sorry for little self promo).